# Quick NSMutableArray Question

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I was wondering, would using a NSMutableArray be the best way for making an array that i will be adding objects to? Or, just a regular NSArray? secondly, I'm trying to make something sort of like an ArrayList in java (so there is no limit to the size), and I would like to know how to do that. What I've thought of is to make a bigger array and copy older array into it. My code:

```
- (void) addAccount:(BankAccount *)b
{

accountCount = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[accountCount doubleValue] + 1];    
NSMutableArray *oldList = accounts;
accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] (some code to make bigger and copy over)];

}
```

P.S. I taught myself this language yesterday, so I may not understand you response if it's too advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMutableArrays are what you want. Also, NSMutableArrays are already like ArrayLists or STL vectors, or anything else with "no limit to the size". You can say `[myArray addObject:someObject];` until you run out of memory, and it will just keep resizing itself as needed.

Comment: Really? So how would I initialize? If I even need to that is, lol

Comment: @Eric: `NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` Should do the trick. You should probably read up on initialization patterns and memory management as well.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between an `NSMutableArray` and an `NSArray` lies in the meaning of the word "mutable". i.e.: A *mutable* array can be modified after it's created whereas a "normal" NSArray is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and can't be modified after it's created.

As such, using an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and adding objects to it via the `addObject:` method would seem an ideal solution.

Comment: @Eric No problems - hope it goes well. (Objective-C and the Cocoa framework are very nice once you get used to the approach used.) :-)

Comment: Yeah it's weird, but I'm getting used it it

Comment: @Eric I'd recommend a good browse of Apple's excellent framework docs - there's a lot of functionality that's available from the "core" classes and the provided sample code is usually pretty good.

Comment: I tried that, but, strangely, the NSMutableArray doc seems o be missing something (XCode has initWithArray, etc and the doc doesn't), unless I'm looking in the wrong place: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Wait, nevermind, those are inherited lol, yeah ill be using this more

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to be adding objects all at once use `NSArray`. If you're going to be adding some objects now, then more later, use `NSMutableArray`.
2. Your code snippet doesn't make much sense. To make an `NSMutableArray`, do this:

   `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: Would I do that in the initialization of my class?

Comment: You can do it wherever you want. If you need an `NSMutableArray` in your initialization method, then create it there, otherwise create it wherever you need it.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is, do I need to initialize? This function is only going to add an object, that's all I'm using the NSArray for right now, because I wouldn't know where to initialize

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need an order (normally you don’t), use a NSSet/NSMutableSet.

Comment: Hmm, also an option, Ill look into that